# Custom Search Scopes in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to add custom custom scope items to a search bar? For example, I want my search bar to be able search through all 4 `label` elements that are on each cell in my table view. Thus, I would need to do something like add those label elements as search scopes.

Any guidance on how to accomplish this?

Comment: [UISearchBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007529-CH3-SW20), accessed from UISearchController via `searchBar`, has some scope properties you might be interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a search bar searches and what it considers success is up to your code.

If you want to modify the search bar *itself* to have labels, use its scope bar and scope button titles. But they do not operate by magic; the search is still up to you.